# Assembly: function template meditation

Tags: function, assembly, x86, stack, gnu-assembler

I'm learning assembly now and I don't get one thing about the (presumably) standard function template.

So, based on [this really nice book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0764579010.html), *"the form to remember for functions is as follows:"*

```
function_label:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    < normal function code goes here>
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

OK, I'm perfectly fine with it, but there is one small thing that I don't understand. After the "normal function code" we restore the initial (pre-call) value of `esp`, which was previously stored in `ebp`.

Now, I understand it clearly why we want to serve the `esp` value back to the calling context untouched. What I do not understand is under which conditions the `esp` value can be changed at all during the function's execution.

Is it some kind of protection against ourselves (in case we somehow corrupt the stack somewhere in our code) included in this template? Or maybe changing stack values inside a function is a normal practice?
Or it is possible that the initial `esp` value may end up changed during execution even if we don't do anything with it? (I can't figure out how this can be, in fact.)

I felt rather silly while thinking about this and checked the `esp` value with `gdb` in this simple code:

```
.section .data
message:
    .asciz "> Hello from function #%d\n"

.section .text
.globl main

main:
    nop
    call    overhere
    pushl   $0
    call    exit
overhere:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   $1
    pushl   $message
    call    printf
    add     $8, %esp
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

And `esp` (as I actually expected) was untouched, so moving `ebp` to `esp` didn't actually change anything.

Now, I hope that it's clear what I want to find out:

- Can `esp` value eventualy change by itself? (I would bet it can't.)
- If it can't, then this template above, obviously, assumes that the programmer might change it somehow inside the function. But I can't figure out why on Earth one might need to do that, so - is changing `esp` value a mistake?

Thank you in advance and excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am puzzled how you missed the instruction that explicitly changes `esp`: `add $8, %esp`. So the answer is clearly yes, it may change during a function and is not a mistake. Note that `push` and `call` also change it, in fact the `add` is to compensate for the two `push` instructions (the `ret` at the end of `printf` will balance the `call`). Other typical reason for changing `esp` is the allocation of local variables. This has been omitted from the function template you showed, it typically looks like `sub $size_of_locals, %esp` right after the `movl %esp, %ebp`.

That said, you don't need to use `ebp` to remember the stack pointer, as long as you ensure it has the same value at the exit of the function as it had upon entry. Recent versions of gcc don't use `ebp` when optimization is enabled, otherwise you can use `-fomit-frame-pointer` to do so.